# SSL cert schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate with VPN

Tags: ssl, curl, ca, buildpack

I read the lot of blogs about the issue but none of the workaround /solutions worked for me.

I am using the curl command like below

```
curl -v  https://golang.org/dl/?mode=json
*   Trying 142.250.80.113:443...
* Connected to golang.org (142.250.80.113) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

I changed the setting in gitbash (windows) to use openssl using the below command

`git config --global http.sslBackend "openssl"`

I am getting the below error after changing openssl

```
$ curl -v  https://golang.org/dl/?mode=json
*   Trying 172.253.62.141:443...
* Connected to golang.org (172.253.62.141) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: C:\Users\AL25229
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I have the CA cert/pem file which my organization provides. I am getting all those error messages when I connect with VPN. Connecting VPN is mandatory. By disabling the VPN, it works fine.

Comment: It reads like your company CA cert file is either not in the cafile `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` or properly placed in the folder `C:\Users\AL25229`. see [this link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/123160/how-to-specifiy-capath-using-openssl-in-windows-to-perform-tls-handshake) for details on the capath's expected format

Comment: Hi @AnyaShenanigans - Thanks for the quick response. It works in Git bash. But it's same issue in CMD. I updated the User Environmental variables like below
CAfile with root.pem & CApath.
As well as I do have entries with SSL_CERT_DIR & SSL_CERT_FILE with root.cer file.
Any help will be really appreciated to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. It's solution for the Linux OS.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try with `--insecure` ?

This will disable the certificate validation and possibly work.

However keep in mind that for production run you should have proper certificates.